# Filtering on several variables with xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a .nc file of oceanographic observations taken at different positions and times. I want to select only those observations that are taken before some date, and within a range of positions. I have tried opening the file with `xarray.open_dataset()` and using `.where` on the dataset, but this seems to use an excessive amount of memory. The .nc file is only 44 MB, but the python process I was running had grown to 21 GB of memory before I killed it.

The datafile I'm using can be downloaded from here: [Norwegian Marine Data Centre](ftp://ftp.nmdc.no/nmdc/IMR/CTD/58GS_CTD_2010.nc)

My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

d = xr.open_dataset('../data/58GS_CTD_2010.nc')
march1 = np.datetime64('2010-03-01T00:00:00.0')
subset = d.where((d.TIME < march1) & ((2 < d.LONGITUDE) & (d.LONGITUDE < 4)) & ((59 < d.LATITUDE) & (d.LATITUDE < 61)))
```

The metadata of the dataset looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (DEPTH: 3357, LATITUDE: 691, LONGITUDE: 691, POSITION: 691, TIME: 691)
Coordinates:
  * TIME         (TIME) datetime64[ns] 2010-05-18T09:33:27.000000256 ... 2010-11-30T17:36:08
  * LATITUDE     (LATITUDE) float32 70.0708 57.0002 56.9983 ... 60.1025 60.4287
  * LONGITUDE    (LONGITUDE) float32 9.5065 3.4033 7.3588 ... 5.4277 5.267
Dimensions without coordinates: DEPTH, POSITION
Data variables:
    TIME_QC      (TIME) float32 ...
    DIRECTION    (TIME) object ...
    POSITION_QC  (POSITION) float32 ...
    DEPH         (TIME, DEPTH) float32 ...
    DEPH_QC      (TIME, DEPTH) float32 ...
    TEMP         (TIME, DEPTH) float32 ...
    TEMP_QC      (TIME, DEPTH) float32 ...
    CNDC         (TIME, DEPTH) float32 ...
    CNDC_QC      (TIME, DEPTH) float32 ...
    PSAL         (TIME, DEPTH) float32 ...
    PSAL_QC      (TIME, DEPTH) float32 ...
Attributes:
    data_type:                  OceanSITES vertical profile
    format_version:             1.2
    platform_code:              MYO_AR_58GS
    platform_name:              G.O. Sars
    date_update:                2017-03-01T09:16:34Z
    institution:                Institute of Marine Research
    site_code:                  
    source:                     Shipborne Observation
    data_mode:                  D
    quality_control_indicator:  5
    quality_index:              A
    references:                 
    comment:                    
    Conventions:                CF-1.6 OceanSITES-Manual-1.2 Copernicus-InSit...
    netcdf_version:             3.5
    title:                      
    summary:                    
    naming_authority:           OceanSITES
    id:                         AR_PR_CT_MYO_AR_58GS_2010
    cdm_data_type:              Point
    area:                       North Atlantic Ocean
    geospatial_lat_min:         56.1492
    geospatial_lat_max:         78.653702
    geospatial_lon_min:         -18.0065
    geospatial_lon_max:         43.095798
    geospatial_vertical_min:    1.0
    geospatial_vertical_max:    3363.0
    institution_references:     http://www.imr.no
    contact:                    datahjelp@imr.no
    author:                     Norwegian Marine Datacenter
    data_assembly_center:       Norwegian Marine Datacenter
    pi_name:                    
    distribution_statement:     These data follow Copernicus standards; they ...
    citation:                   These data were collected and made freely ava...
    update_interval:            void
    qc_manual:                  OceanSITES User's Manual v1.1
    wmo_platform_code:          
    history:                    
    time_coverage_start:        2010-01-29T15:07:40Z
    time_coverage_end:          2010-11-30T17:36:08Z
```

Comment: Why do you need to filter on the position, if LATITUDE and LONGITUDE are not used as dimensions for your variables? 

Normally in xarray you use `.sel()` to select data based on dimensions. In this case you can only use it with TIME as it is used as dimension for your variables, and using `.where()` to filter on LATITUDE and LONGITUDE won't make a difference. 

Anyway, you can first chunk your data to avoid memory issues:

`subset = d.chunk({'TIME':50,'LATITUDE':50,'LONGITUDE':50}).where(mask, drop=True)`

Comment: Each observation is taken at some time, and some position, so each observation has a time, a longitude and a latitude associated with it. But I didn't think of the fact that only time is a dimension of the variables. I guess it doesn't even make sens to make them all dimensions, since they are not independent variables (at some time, only one observation was taken, at some longitude and latitude, so you cannot choose position independently of time). What I was trying to do was similar to filtering on several columns in a pandas DataFrame, so maybe I should just try using a DataFrame instead.

Comment: I'm still curious about the ginormous memory footprint, though. Even if I was trying to do something that doesn't make sense, why would the process require almost 100 times more memory than the size of the file?

Comment: Yep that's still quite odd. I don't know xarray in detail enough to answer to that question with certainty, but my guess is that the `.where()` method somewhere is broadcasting the arrays by expanding onto new dimensions (LATITUDE and LONGITUDE), resulting in arrays of TIMExDEPTHxLONGITUDExLATITUDE (you do the math...huge arrays!).
Anyway did the chunking work?

Comment: In the end, I didn't try chunking, I created a separate boolean 1D array and used that as a mask. I'll wait a bit and see if any other suggestions show up, and if not I'll post it as an answer.